# How can I find my application's icon?

Tags: c++, windows, icons, application-resource

I am trying to load the icon associated with the application that called my function.

The way I am solving the problem for GUI applications is this:

```
AfxGetApp()->LoadIcon(128); // 128 is the IDR_MAINFRAME icon
```

However, the Afx functions, upon looking up the resource, fail for some non-gui applications, since `afxCurrentResourceHandle` is NULL.

What would be a better way to find the mainframe icon?

PS. currently I can work around it by testing `afxCurrentResourceHandle != NULL`... wish I could do better.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you're assuming that only MFC applications will be calling your function.  If so, how about:

```
HICON hIcon = AfxGetMainWnd()->GetIcon( TRUE );
```

Comment: I specifically run into trouble for console apps.  Not sure what makes them an "MFC" app or not.  Thanks for the attempt, but `TRUE` is a macro indicating boolean logic, and the `GetIcon` specifically asks for a `UINT` argument.  In other words: this should not compile; it only does by grace of the `TRUE` macro being defined as an integer.

Comment: You are incorrect, sir.  AfxGetMainWnd() returns a CWnd pointer.  The signature for CWnd::GetIcon is: HICON CWnd::GetIcon( BOOL bBigIcon ).  Check the docs.  Thanks for the minus 1, dude.